# Node.js для работы с Phonegap

Tags: node.js, npm, phonegap

Во всех инструкциях по работе с *Phonegap* написано, что перед началом работы необходимо установить *Node.js*. Правильно ли я понимаю, что он нужен только для того, чтобы через пакетный менеджер *npm* установить собственно *Phonegap*? То есть для написания мобильных приложений с помощью *Phonegap* будет достаточно установить только *npm package manager*?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опытным путём было установлено, что да, для написания мобильных приложений с помощью *Phonegap* достаточно установить только *npm package manager*.